# Products shared among multiple companies under different categories - sql table design

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

How to I represent the following datamodel in sql tables.

I have 3 entities, `company, productcategory and product`.

Business model is that Company can have product category1-N and each category can have many products.

The trick is that products are shared across companies under different categories. Product categories are not shared. Each company has its own categories.

for example,

```
product1 belongs to category1 under company1

product1 belongs to category2 under company2
```

I'm thinking of having the following tables. Only relevant Id fields are shown below.

### Company

CompanyId

### ProductCategory

ProductCategoryId

CompanyId

ParentCategoryId (To support levels)

### Product

ProductId

### ProductCategoryXProduct

ProductCategoryId

ProductId

This way I can query for all product categories for a product and filter by company to get the specific category structure for its products. This may be different for another company even if the product is the same.

Will this cover it? is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a fine [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) design that fits what you have described.

Note that as your data set will grow, this design will start slowing down (mostly due to the required joins), so when the time comes you may want to denormalize some of these tables for faster reads.

Comment: i did not completely understand the link you sent. Is 3NF different from the model I describe above?

Comment: @AlexJ - Don't sweat it. I am saying that your design is a valid third normal form design. I suggest you read up on the different normal forms.

Comment: ok, will do. Why do you say that this will be slow as data grows. There is only one extra join for productcategoryXproduct which only contains ids. If I have to denormalize (as you mention at a later stage), how do you recommend I do it.

Comment: @AlexJ - I am talking about many millions of rows, and this is just a consequence of having lots of data that needs to join. As for how to do it... every case is unique. It will depend on the application and what data it requires.

Comment: I have dealt with millions of rows in the past. Some good indexes should take care of that for read only queries, hopefully :)

Comment: @AlexJ - They should for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the need for products to belong to multiple categories I think that this structure is fine.

Comment: yes, the products will belong to multiple categories (under different companies). Under one company, it will belong to only one category.